# Given $y_1,\cdots,y_N\in \mathbb{R}$, find $\mathbf{x}_1,\cdots,\mathbf{x}_N\in \mathbb{R}^K$, subject to some linear constraints.

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

Assume that $y_1,\cdots,y_N\in \mathbb{R}$ are known.

Now I want to find a set of $\mathbf{x}_1,\cdots,\mathbf{x}_N\in \mathbb{R}^K$, such that $y_n=\mathbf{x}_n^T\mathbf{a}$, $\sum_{n=1}^N\mathbf{x}_n=\mathbf{b}$ and $0\le\mathbf{x}_n\le1$.

More clearly:

$Find\quad \mathbf{x}_1,\cdots,\mathbf{x}_N\in \mathbb{R}^K\\
s.t.\quad y_n=\mathbf{x}_n^T\mathbf{a}\\
\quad\quad \sum_{n=1}^N\mathbf{x}_n=\mathbf{b}\\
\quad\quad 0\le\mathbf{x}_n\le1 $

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: The condition are quite restricive and in most cases you won't find a solution... but a full answer would incluse a case-division based on the Rank of $a$

Comment: This is a linear programming feasibility problem. For general $y$, $b$ there is not going to be a closed-form solution. And it could have 0, 1, or an infinite number of solutions. A decent convex/LP modeling framework should have no trouble helping you find a solution.